# JavaScript missing from shortcode content

Tags: shortcode, callbacks

I am trying to add a short javascript as part of registering a WP shortcode. You can see my simplified code below. When I execute this on my website everything loads fine except for the part between the `<script> ... </script>` tags. I looked at the source code after the page has loaded and neither the `<script>` tags nor the function in between is there.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Is there a filter in WP that removes `<script>` tags?

Thank you!

```
// register custom shortcodes
function psb_register_shortcodes() {
    add_shortcode('psb-booking', 'psb_booking_shortcode');
}

function psb_booking_shortcode( $args, $content='' ) {
    global $wpdb; 
    $output = 
        '<script>
             function doSomething () {};
         </script>';
    $output .= '<p> testing </p>';
    
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'psb_booking';
    foreach ( $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare("DESC " . $table_name, 0 )) as $column_name ) {
        error_log( $column_name );
    }
    
    $output .= file_get_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/psb-booking.html');

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: I know it doesn't technically answer your question ("Is there a filter in WP..." but enqueuing a script to the footer when the shortcode is called by using [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/), would answer your needs, yes?

Comment: @CelsoBessa, the Javascript I'm trying to add is a var structure which is created dynamically from the wpdb. I thought I could add the php code to create that var here in the callback function. Since it's dynamically created I can't use `wp_enqueue_script`, at least I don't know how.